# Access Query by form using more than one parameter in one field

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I have a form that I am using to populate a query. I have given a code snippet below. There are multiple fields for the user to enter information as to narrow a report down. I found the below code and it works great if the user only wants to make one selection per category i.e. "status" = C. My issue is that there are cases where the user may be looking for more than one status at one time. If I enter in C or S into the form right now the query populates with *C or S* which will yield no results since it should be "C" or "S" or *C* or *S*. Can anybody help me convert this code to allow for inputting multiple values and reading it into the query correctly?

```
Function SearchCriteria()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim tblname, strqry As String
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set dbs = CurrentDb

Dim allexists As QueryDef

strqry = "All Selected"

tblname = "SelectionWeeklyAuto1000"

On Error GoTo err_handler

Set allexists = dbs.QueryDefs("All Selected")

err_handler:
  Select Case Err.Number
  Case 3265

    strSQL = "SELECT " & tblname & ".* From " & tblname & " WHERE (1=1)"

    Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef(strqry)
    qdf.SQL = strSQL
    DoCmd.Save

End Select

DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, strqry


Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef(strqry)

strSQL = "SELECT " & tblname & ".* From " & tblname & " WHERE (1=1)"

If Not IsNull([Forms]![Report Tool]![Text1]) Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " And ([Screen] Like ""*" & [Forms]![Report Tool]![Text1] & "*"")"

End If

If Not IsNull([Forms]![Report Tool]![Text2]) Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " And ([Status] Like ""*" & [Forms]![Report Tool]![Text2] & "*"")"

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ignoring the fact that your main question is using `=` and the code snippet is using `Like`, I would extend the code snippet as

```
strSQL = strSQL & " And ([Status] Like ""*" & Replace([Forms]![Report Tool]![Text2], " or ", "*"" Or [Status] Like ""*") & "*"")"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @Skippy. It works exactly as I was hoping it would. Hopefully as I learn I will get better at presenting the question.